# FlexBox container not responsive

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm having trouble making my layout responsive
basically I only have one header and when I'm at lower resolutions the screen is completely buggy

the background which is 100vh and 100vw does not work

image:

[image]

in desktop resolution:

[image]

code:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="Wrapper">
      <div className="Header">
        <div className="navtop Container">

          <div className="LogoHeader">
            <a>
              <img className="img" src={Logo} />
            </a>
          </div>

          <div className="SearchWrapper">
            <form className="form">
              <input className="input" />
            </form>
          </div>


          <nav className="NavWrapper">a</nav>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

css:

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
#root {
    height: 100vh !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.Wrapper{
    height: 100% !important;
    background: red;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.Header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 140px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background: rgb(113, 89, 193);
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}
.navtop{
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    background:yellow;
}
.Container{
    max-width: 1140px;
    padding: 0px 30px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.LogoHeader {
    background: red;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 15px;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 10em;
  }

  .img {
    width: 150px;
  }
  .SearchWrapper {
    background: yellow;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .input {
    min-width: 200px;
  }
  .input:focus {
    min-width: 300px;
  }

  .NavWrapper {
    background: black;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

i really tried every possible solution i know i could change that with media queries
but i know i did something wrong in my css so i'm having this

Comment: `.img{ width: 150px }` 、 `input{ min-width: 200px }` 、 `.Container { padding: 0 30px; }` 、`.LogoHeader { padding: 0 15px; }` 
(150px + 200px + 60px + 30px) = 440px > 100vw

Comment: u can post reply for check? I didn't understand well

Comment: Yes, @多一点点爱 is correct..  if you add up the width and padding of all those elements, they have a min-width of at least 440px.  You need to adjust the width and padding of all those elements so that they can shrink to at least 320px or more.

Comment: As' Bryan Elliott 'says，Also note that 'input' has a default minimum width when no width is set. e.g: `169px`, The width of 'flex' child elements is limited by the width of internal elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're aiming at, but there are at least 3 elements that are causing your header to not be able to shrink down fully to a mobile width below 440px.

Adjusting these 3 elements will get you going in the right direction, like so:

```css
.LogoHeader {
    background: red;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 15px;
    height: 100%;
    /*min-width: 10em;*/ /*REMOVE THIS LINE*/
    width: 100%; /*ADD THIS*/
    max-width: 10em; /*ADD THIS*/
}
.img {
    /*width: 150px;*/ /*REMOVE THIS LINE*/
    width: 100%; /*ADD THIS*/
    max-width: 150px; /*ADD THIS*/
    height: auto; /*ADD THIS */
}
.input {
    /*min-width: 200px;*/ /*REMOVE THIS LINE*/
    width: 100%; /*ADD THIS*/
    max-width: 200px; /*ADD THIS*/
    min-width: 50px; /*ADD THIS*/
}
```

Or you could adjust these elements in a media query, like so:

```css
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .LogoHeader {
    min-width: unset;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 10em;
  }
  .image {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 150px;
    height: auto;
  }
  .input {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 200px;
    min-width: 50px;
  }
}
```

Of course, you may want to adjust the values as needed and make some other modifications, but this should at lease allow the header to shrink down to mobile width.

The point here is that `.img` had a fixed with `150px` and the `input` had a min-width of `200px`, and the `.LogoHeader` had a min-width of `10em` so those fixed widths and min-widths along with the padding of the  `.Container` and `.LogoHeader` was not allowing your entire `Header` to shrink below `440px`.

Comment: I think I understood
 so the problem was my definition of width in the elements

is there any way to fix this without using the media query?

Comment: @gabriel, there.. answer edited..  try that.. That should get you going :)

Comment: thanks bro, I think the only solution would be a media query even hehe
could you put that example of media query too?

I could put in more than one class or have what to do a media query for each class:

Comment: @gabriel, Ok, I edited the answer and added the media query and added further explanation. :)